# ReferenceError: document is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I am using vanilla javascript in my file. However, I keep getting the error below. Why?

```
file:///Users/rizalmahadiab/Desktop/ga/unit1/project/concentration-game/app.mjs:30
document
^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at file:///Users/rizalmahadiab/Desktop/ga/unit1/project/concentration-game/app.mjs:30:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)
```

Comment: Where/How are you running this code?

Comment: `document` doesn't exist in the nodejs environment.

Answer (score 2):

You are running this in Node. The `document` global object only exists in browsers.